# Searching Through Google +1 Links

Tags: google-plus-one

I do a lot of searches to answer specific questions I have (usually programming related). When I find an answer I +1 the page using the [+1 Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgoepmocgafhnchmokaimcmlojpnlkhp). I don't like to bookmark pages like these, because my bookmarks fill up with links to pages that I can't remember viewing.

If I end up Googling the same question again, seeing that I have +1'ed a particular page saves me a heap of time. But what I would really like to do is search through only the pages that I have +1'ed.

The problem is that the [+1 API](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) is all about displaying the +1 button, not accessing the list of URLs you have +1'ed. Does anyone know if it is possible to somehow search through the complete list of you +1'ed items (and I already know about the +1 list in Google+)?